# How can process become a member of a process group?

Tags: process, process-groups

How can process become a member of a PGRP?

My attempt: *Process needs to be a child of a PGRP's leader or we need to use a system call **setpgid()**.*

Also, another two questions.

1) How can process become a leader of a group?
*I can only think about creating a new process, which will automatically become a leader*

2) Can group have many leaders?
*I think it is impossible, but can't find any information about this*

Are my answers correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can only think about creating a new process, *which will automatically become a leader*

False.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    printf("%d member of %d\n", getpid(), getpgrp());
    return 0;
}
```

The new process shares the group of the parent:

```
$ make leadership
cc -g    leadership.c   -o leadership
$ ./leadership
65617 member of 65617
65618 member of 65617
$
```

Only with `setpgid(2)` or `setsid(2)` or similar system calls will the group or leadership change.

> 2) Can group have many leaders?

False. Quoting from Stevens, "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" (2nd ed.), chapter 9 section 4 (p. 243):

> "Each process group can have a process group leader. The leader is identified by having its process group ID equal to its process ID."

Singular leader, and a very specific case for identifying said leader.